# HTTPS ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I recently switched my site to use HTTPS. I am using Laravel as a php framework. At the beginning I had an issue where I would get a 'Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.' error, but then I had fixed that by using this in my filters.php:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
});
```

The is the ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/media/search/',
            data: { 'q':search_string },
            success: function(d) { }
    });
```

Now instead of the Cross Origin error I am getting a redirect to my login page instead of the content that should be loaded. I think it has something to do with the CSRF token implementation that Laravel has, but I am not sure of the route I should take to either add that token to the request or how I could fix it. Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT:

If I don't have those header functions in my filter.php I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://website.com/media/search?&q=500. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://website.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

After this I had proceeded to use this call instead:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://website.com/media/search/',
        data: { 'q':search_string },
        success: function(d) { }
});
```

but still no luck

Comment: you are not making a cross domain call here. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not required.

Comment: please see my edit, I couldn't figure out how to force https on the ajax call. I would put https://website/search/' on my call, but it would still call to http

Comment: http <-> https is considered cross domain; use the same protocol for the ajax call

Comment: Can you post some more code ? Where in your code does it redirect you ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's related to CRSF you could remove AJAX from it:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (!Request::ajax() && Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

adding `!Request::ajax()` rule at the beginning. You could also add `_token` to your data.

You should also look at your `app/config/session.php` file :

```
'secure' => false,
```

if it is set to true and you make AJAX request from http it might not work

Comment: it's cSrf (cross site request forgery). If it was csrf filter throwing exception, why would he end up in the login page? An auth filter (or some controller redirect) would make more sense.

Comment: @alou It depends how CSRF filter is defined. It can be defined to log out user and redirect to login page.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work. I am still redirected to the login page.

Comment: @AndrewButler I've edited my answer. You should make more debugging to know where you go. Do you go in a controller which check authentication or is it a filter. Without it it might be hard to guess what's going on

Comment: on the controller I have the default auth filter on the search controller: If(Auth::guest() return Redirect::guest('/signin'); but I figured it wouldn't be a guest if it was making a request through the session, no?

Comment: Session doesn't mean authenticated (logged in) user, unless search is allowed only to authenticated users you shouldn't use that filter, just csrf.